# TypeError: 'DictWriter' object is not iterable

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm working on creating a short simple program for a nonprofit fundraiser to validate ticket numbers as guests check in to make sure no duplicate tickets are redeemed.  I'm running Python 3.4.3 on a Windows 10 machine.  Once the program is finalized it will be used on a Raspberry Pi with touchscreen at the fundraiser.

I've tried a couple different methods to build the list, save it, and search for duplicates.  Ideally the list will be stored in a CSV file, but a plain text or other format is ok too.

Can you help me with the traceback error (TypeError: 'DictWriter' object is not iterable) due to the looping function to check ticket #'s against a list stored in a file to make sure no duplicate tickets are redeemed?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
version = "v1.4"
fname="tickets.csv"
import csv
import datetime
import os.path
print("\nWelcome to TicketCheck", version)
extant = os.path.isfile(fname)
with open(fname, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['ticketid', 'timestamp']
    ticketwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if extant == False:
        ticketwriter.writeheader()
    while True:
        ticket = ""
        print("Please enter a ticket # to continue or type exit to exit:")
        ticket = str(input())
        if ticket == "":
            continue
        if ticket == "exit":
            break
        print("You entered ticket # %s." % (ticket))
        print("Validating ticket...")
        for row in ticketwriter:
            if row[0] == ticket:
                print("\n\n\n===== ERROR!!! TICKET # %s ALREADY CHECKED IN =====\n\n\n" % (ticket))
                continue
        time = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("Thank you for checking in ticket # %s at %s \n\n\n" % (ticket, time))
        print("Ticket is now validated.")
        ticketwriter.writerow({'ticketid': ticket, 'timestamp': time})
        csvfile.flush()
        continue
csvfile.close()
print("All your work has been saved in %s.\n Thank you for using TicketCheck %s \n" % (fname, version))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I think you might be over-complicating this a bit! For something like that there's really no need to go to all that trouble. This is a great spot to use a dictionary, and for something with only two inputs, the id and the check-in time, you can easily just make a .txt log. I get the feeling this might be more of what you are looking for.

```
import time
go = True
while go:
    the_guestlist = {}
    the_ticket = input().strip()
    file = open('somefile.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        my_items = line.split(',')
        the_guestlist[my_items[0]] = my_items[1]
    file.close()
    if the_ticket in the_guestlist.keys():
        print("Sorry, that ticket has been entered at {}".format(the_guestlist[the_ticket]))
    elif the_ticket == 'exit':
        go = False
        print('Exiting...')
    else:
        the_guestlist[the_ticket] = '{}'.format(time.asctime())
        file = open('somefile.txt', 'a')
        file.write(the_ticket +','+the_guestlist[the_ticket]+'\n')
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects of the [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class are not iterable, *i.e.* you cannot iterate over them like you would a dictionary, list, or even string, hence your error message. It does not store the data you have previously written to file, only the file you wrote to stores that data.

To achieve your goal, you could do two things: either open your CSV file every time a new ticket needs to be validated, and check if the ticket number is present, or - since you are using relatively small amounts of data - store a dictionary in memory, and only write it out at the end of use, checking from that if the ticket is valid.